# How would one succinctly compare the values of and call the functions of many derived classes' base class?

Tags: c++, iteration, sfml, derived-class, base-class

I have a 2d physics engine that I've been programming in C++ using SFML; I've implemented a rough collision detection system for all `SandboxObject`s (*the base class for every type of physics object*), but I have a dilemma.

I plan to have many different derived classes of `SandboxObject`s, such as `Circle`s, `Rect`s, and so on, but I want a way to check if the `roughHitbox` of each `SandboxObject` collides with another.

When the program starts, it allocates memory for, let's say, 10,000 `Circles`

```cpp
int circleCount = 0;//the number of active Circles
constexpr int m_maxNumberOfCircles = 10000;//the greatest number of circles able to be set active
Circle* m_circles = new Circle[m_maxNumberOfCircles];//create an array of circles that aren't active by default
```

like so.

and every time the user 'spawns' a new `Circle`, the code runs

```cpp
(m_circles + circleCount)->setActive();`
circleCount++
```

`Circle`s that aren't alive essentially do not exist at all; they might have positions and radii, but that info will **never** be used if that `Circle` is not active.

Given all this, what I want to do is to loop over *all* the different arrays of derived classes of `SandboxObject` because `SandboxObject` is the base class which implements the rough hitbox stuff, but because there will be many different derived classes, I don't know the best way to go about it.

One approach I did try (with little success) was to have a pointer to a `SandboxObject`

```cpp
SandboxObject* m_primaryObjectPointer = nullptr;
```

this pointer would be null unless there were > 1 `SandboxObject`s active; with it, I tried using increment and decrement functions that checked if it could point to the next `SandboxObject`, but I couldn't get that to work properly because a base class pointer to a derived class acts funky. :/

I'm not looking for exact code implementations, just a proven method for working with the base class of many different derived classes.

Let me know if there's anything I should edit in this question or if there's any more info I could provide.

Comment: Two (unrelated) points: Don't do you own explicit memory handling. For a container of objects, use `std::vector`. Secondly, `(m_circles + circleCount)->setActive();` is exactly equal to `m_circles[circleCount].setActive();`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand.

Comment: More related to your problem, are the class polymorphic? Then why not use a single `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SandboxObjects>>` for all *active* objects? Then you don't have to keep track of any "inactive" objects, since they won't even exist. And since you have a single container for all "active" objects, you can more easily iterate over them as needed.

Comment: Have you considered a static vector within the SandboxObject class that holds pointers to all of the objects that have been created. Within your SandboxObject constructor you can have
    m_all_objects.push_back(this);

The destructor would have to set the pointer to nullptr, which you can then check for.

Comment: You may find a better pool of experience in the gamedev stack exchange https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are caused by your desire to use a polymorphic approach on non-polymorphic containers.

The advantage of a `SandboxObject* m_primaryObjectPointer` is that it allows you to treat your objects polymorphicaly: `m_primaryObjectPointer -> roughtHitBox()`  will work regardless of the object's real type being `Circle`, `Rectangle`, or a `Decagon`.

But iterating using `m_primaryObjectPointer++` will not work as you expect:  this iteration assumes that you iterate over contiguous objects in an array of `SandboxObject` elements (i.e. the compiler will use the base type's memory layout to compute the next address).

Instead,  you may consider iterating over a vector (or an array if you really want to deal with extra memory management hassle) of pointers.

```
vector<SandboxObject*> universe;  
populate(universe); 
for (auto object:unviverse) {
    if (object->isActive()) {
        auto hb = object -> roughtHitBox(); 
        // do something with that hitbox
    }
}
```

Now managing the objects in the universe can be painful as well.  You may therefore consider using smart pointers instead:

```
vector<shared_ptr<SandboxObject>> universe;
```

(little [demo](https://ideone.com/zPnMPA))

Comment: "But iterating using m_primaryObjectPointer++ will not work as you expect" aye, I found that out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without knowing the requirements but you could have `sandbox` maintain two vectors of active and inactive objects, and use unique_ptrs of the base class for memory management.

Some code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class sandbox_object {
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class circle : public sandbox_object {
private:
    float x_, y_, radius_;
public:
    circle(float x, float y, float r) :
        x_(x), y_(y), radius_(r)
    {}

    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "i'm a circle.\n";
    }
};

class triangle : public sandbox_object {
private:
    float x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, x3_, y3_;
public:
    triangle( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) :
        x1_(x1), y1_(y1), x2_(x2), y2_(y2), x3_(x3), y3_(y3)
    {}

    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "i'm a triangle.\n";
    }
};

class sandbox {
    using sandbox_iterator = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sandbox_object>>::iterator;
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sandbox_object>> active_objects_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sandbox_object>> inactive_objects_;
public:
    void insert_circle(float x, float y, float r) {
        active_objects_.push_back( std::make_unique<circle>(x, y, r) );
    }

    void insert_triangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) {
        active_objects_.push_back( std::make_unique<triangle>(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3));
    }

    sandbox_iterator active_objs_begin() {
        return active_objects_.begin();
    }

    sandbox_iterator active_objs_end() {
        return active_objects_.end();
    }

    void make_inactive(sandbox_iterator iter) {
        std::unique_ptr<sandbox_object> obj = std::move(*iter);
        active_objects_.erase(iter);
        inactive_objects_.push_back(std::move(obj));
    }

};

int main() {
    sandbox sb;

    sb.insert_circle(10.0f, 10.0f, 2.0f);
    sb.insert_triangle(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    sb.insert_circle(1.0f, 6.0f, 4.0f);

    sb.make_inactive(sb.active_objs_begin());
    (*sb.active_objs_begin())->do_something(); // this should be the triangle...

    return 0;
}
```